# Opensips not generating BYE message to client

Tags: opensips

I'm using `opensips` as a transparent proxy server. Original flow of messages is following

```
Client -------> OpenSips (Invite request)
OpenSips ------------> FS (Invite to Freeswitch)
FS -------------> Opensips (Reply from FreeSwitch)
Opensips ------------------> Client (Reply back to Client)
```

I'm using `dialog module` to save dialog state and `topological_hiding` module to change `contact header`. It's working fine until `FreeSwitch` send `BYE` message. On `Freeswitch BYE`, `opensips` generate `404 not here` response.

According to configuration of `opensips` `loose_route()` return `false`. **Opensips** never `send BYE` to client.

**Note: BYE message has same dialog as Invite request.**

Answer (score 0):

When using `topology_hiding()`, you must match sequential requests using `topology_hiding_match()`, rather than `loose_route()`. So if you're doing something like this:

```
if (has_totag()) {
    if (!loose_route()) {
        xlog("cannot match request to a dialog\n");
        send_reply("404", "Not found");
    }
    route(RELAY);
}
```

you should change it to:

```
if (has_totag()) {
    if (!topology_hiding_match()) {
        xlog("cannot match request to a dialog\n");
        send_reply("404", "Not found");
    }
    route(RELAY);
}
```